# K-shortest path algorithm for python 3

Tags: python-3.x, path, networkx, shortest

I have tried an available K-shortest path algorithm. But it gives an error and i cannot figure out what it is. I want to find two shortest paths between two network nodes.
It gives an error saying that int type is not iterable and i do not know how to solve it.

```
import sys
#sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()
import simpy
import random
import math
#import run_parameters
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from itertools import count

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


"""
A NetworkX based implementation of Yen's algorithm for computing K-shortest paths.
Yen's algorithm computes single-source K-shortest loopless paths for a
graph with non-negative edge cost. For more details, see:
http://networkx.github.io
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm
"""
__author__ = 'Guilherme Maia <guilhermemm@gmail.com>'

__all__ = ['k_shortest_paths']

from heapq import heappush, heappop
from itertools import count

import networkx as nx

def k_shortest_paths(G, source, target, k=2, weight='weight'):
    """Returns the k-shortest paths from source to target in a weighted graph G.
    Parameters
    ----------
    G : NetworkX graph
    source : node
       Starting node
    target : node
       Ending node
`
    k : integer, optional (default=1)
        The number of shortest paths to find
    weight: string, optional (default='weight')
       Edge data key corresponding to the edge weight
    Returns
    -------
    lengths, paths : lists
       Returns a tuple with two lists.
       The first list stores the length of each k-shortest path.
       The second list stores each k-shortest path.
    Raises
    ------
    NetworkXNoPath
       If no path exists between source and target.
    Examples
    --------
    >>> G=nx.complete_graph(5)
    >>> print(k_shortest_paths(G, 0, 4, 4))
    ([1, 2, 2, 2], [[0, 4], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 4]])
    Notes
    ------
    Edge weight attributes must be numerical and non-negative.
    Distances are calculated as sums of weighted edges traversed.
    """
    if source == target:
        return ([0], [[source]])

    length, path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, source, target, weight=weight)
    if target not in length:
        raise nx.NetworkXNoPath("node %s not reachable from %s" % (source, target))

    lengths = [length[target]]
    paths = [path[target]]
    c = count()
    B = []
    G_original = G.copy()

    for i in range(1, k):
        for j in range(len(paths[-1]) - 1):
            spur_node = paths[-1][j]
            root_path = paths[-1][:j + 1]

            edges_removed = []
            for c_path in paths:
                if len(c_path) > j and root_path == c_path[:j + 1]:
                    u = c_path[j]
                    v = c_path[j + 1]
                    if G.has_edge(u, v):
                        edge_attr = G.edge[u][v]
                        G.remove_edge(u, v)
                        edges_removed.append((u, v, edge_attr))

            for n in range(len(root_path) - 1):
                node = root_path[n]
                # out-edges
                for u, v, edge_attr in G.edges_iter(node, data=True):
                    G.remove_edge(u, v)
                    edges_removed.append((u, v, edge_attr))

                if G.is_directed():
                    # in-edges
                    for u, v, edge_attr in G.in_edges_iter(node, data=True):
                        G.remove_edge(u, v)
                        edges_removed.append((u, v, edge_attr))

            spur_path_length, spur_path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, spur_node, target, weight=weight)
            if target in spur_path and spur_path[target]:
                total_path = root_path[:-1] + spur_path[target]
                total_path_length = get_path_length(G_original, root_path, weight) + spur_path_length[target]
                heappush(B, (total_path_length, next(c), total_path))

            for e in edges_removed:
                u, v, edge_attr = e
                G.add_edge(u, v, edge_attr)

        if B:
            (l, _, p) = heappop(B)
            lengths.append(l)
            paths.append(p)
        else:
            break

    return (lengths, paths)

def get_path_length(G, path, weight='weight'):
    length = 0
    if len(path) > 1:
        for i in range(len(path) - 1):
            u = path[i]
            v = path[i + 1]

            length += G.edge[u][v].get(weight, 1)

    return length

G=nx.complete_graph(5)
print(k_shortest_paths(G, 0, 4, 4))
```

Why it gives this error? In some cases it works for k=1, but when i increase k to 2, the error comes.

Comment: Have you tried using the implementation that comes in networkx?  `shortest_simple_paths`. 
 [documentation is here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths)

Comment: It will be much easier to say what causes the error if you post the entire error message (the full traceback).

Comment: Let me go a bit farther - I don't think anyone will want to put in the effort to  read this many lines of code without knowing which line triggers the error.  We'll need to see the entire error message.